# How to show time values in stacked column using High stock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to created stacked columns in Highstock. in following js fiddle.
The code is

```
    //http://jsfiddle.net/nishants/y0t130f3/2/

    $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart',{
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Stacked column chart'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [new Date(2014, 5, 30).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 29).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 28).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 27).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 26).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 25).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 24).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 23).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 22).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 21).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 20).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 19).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 18).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 17).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 16).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 15).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 14).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 13).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 12).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 11).getTime()/1000 ]
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Total fruit consumption'
                },
                stackLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -70,
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 20,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
                borderColor: '#CCC',
                borderWidth: 1,
                shadow: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '' + this.x + '
' +
                        this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '
' +
                        'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                        style: {
                            textShadow: '0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'John',
                data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2,5, 3, 4, 7, 2,5, 3, 4, 7, 2,5, 3, 4, 7, 2,]
            }, {
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1,2, 2, 3, 2, 1,2, 2, 3, 2, 1,2, 2, 3, 2, 1,]
            }, {
                name: 'Joe',
                data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5,3, 4, 4, 2, 5,3, 4, 4, 2, 5,3, 4, 4, 2, 5,]
            }]
        });
    });
```

The code on x axis should be dates from 11/05/2014 to 30/05/2014 . I tried all new Date
unix time stamp and unix time stamp /1000. but nothing works. What I want to achieve is
very straight forward => How to put the dates on x axis of highstock.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike HighCharts, I don't think HighStock support the `xAxis.categories` config.

However, you could specify the dates directly in `serie.data` like this:

```
{
    name: 'John',
    data: [
        [new Date(2014, 5, 11).getTime(), 5],
        [new Date(2014, 5, 12).getTime(), 3],
        [new Date(2014, 5, 13).getTime(), 4],
        ...
    ]
}
```

And the **dates must be in ascending order**, otherwise the chart will be broken.

Another thing is you might want to set this to make columns align with date labels correctly.

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {

        ...

        dataGrouping: {
            enabled: true,
            forced: true,
            units: [
                ['day', [1]]
            ]
        }
    }
},
```

**Example JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/1xLny72q/2/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

When we make Highstock graph by series then we can't pass x-axis seprated data as per like Highchart
like in your code

```
 xAxis: {
                categories: [new Date(2014, 5, 30).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 29).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 28).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 27).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 26).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 25).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 24).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 23).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 22).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 21).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 20).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 19).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 18).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 17).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 16).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 15).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 14).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 13).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 12).getTime()/1000,new Date(2014, 5, 11).getTime()/1000 ]
            },
```

its not work in HighStock

for this you need to pass these each separate value on each series like below

```
{
    name: 'John',
    data: [
        [new Date(2014, 5, 11).getTime(), 5],
        [new Date(2014, 5, 12).getTime(), 3],
        ...
    ]
},name: 'Jane',

          data: [
        [new Date(2014, 5, 11).getTime(), 2],
        [new Date(2014, 5, 12).getTime(), 3],
        ...
    ])
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
             data: [
        [new Date(2014, 5, 11).getTime(), 5],
        [new Date(2014, 5, 12).getTime(), 4],
        ...
    ]}
```

and as per @ranTarm **dates must be in ascending order**  and **dataGrouping** as mention  in his comment

Comment: Instead of new Date(2014, 5, 11).getTime() you can use Date.UTC();